# Magento hiding shopping basket and price injection

Tags: php, magento, code-injection

i have changed the magento code in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\design\frontend\mypackage\mytheme\template\catalog\product\list.phtml
C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\design\frontend\mypackage\mytheme\template\catalog\product\price.phtml

inorder to show prices only if the user is logged in and also to hide the shopping basket button and price when a product has 0.00 price 
my issue is that i dont want the user to use injection methods to bypass this so my question is is my code vurnerable to sql injection ?

```
  <!-- To hide price if price is 0 if not display the details  -->
                <?php if($_product->price==0): ?>
     <?php  echo ''; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
     <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
    <?php endif; ?> 

                <div class="actions">
                 <!-- To hide the shopping basket  -->
     <?php if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()): ?> 
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable() && ($_product->price>0)): ?>
                        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart')  ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Auf anfrage') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
     <!-- if they are not logged in then  -->               
<?php else: ?>
<p class="nurfuer"><span><?php echo 'only for registered users'?></span></p>
<p class="nurfuer"><span><?php echo 'please register'?></span></p>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

and also in the price.phtml file i added

```
<?php if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) { ?> 
and at the end of the file
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no SQL in your approach, so it stands to reason that this code is not viable for SQL injection.

To answer the underlying question;

> Can users which are not logged in, still add products to the basket or
>   view prices?

You have not done anything to block a user from using direct url's to achieve a certain goal. When you add a product to the basket, you invoke a certain url. Users can still invoke such an url to add something to their basket. When people want to view their basket, they invoke a url, which can still be invoked...

To really make sure, you will have to have 'logged-in'-checks on the controllers/actions as well.